# How do I compare the cardinality of these two specific sets?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Consider the following three sets:
>
> - $\mathcal A=\{a\mid a\textrm{ is an author}\}$
> - $\mathcal B=\{b\mid b\textrm{ is a book title}\}$
> - $\mathcal W=\bigl\{(r,k)\mid r\in\mathcal A,k\in\mathcal B;\textrm{ book }k\textrm{ written by author }r\bigr\}$
>
> How does the cardinality $|\mathcal A\times\mathcal B|$ compare with the cardinality $|\mathcal W|$? Is it less than, equal, or greater than? Why?

An example I was given is this:

$\mathcal A = \{\textrm{JRR Tolkien}, \textrm{Jane Austen}, \textrm{Virgil}\}$

$\mathcal B = \{\textit{Lord of The Rings}, \textit{Pride and Prejudice}, \textit{Iliad}\}$

$\mathcal W = \bigl\{(\textrm{JRR Tolkien}, \textit{Lord of The Rings}), (\textrm{Jane Austen}, \textit{Pride and Prejudice})\bigr\}$

Please help :(

Comment: If you know what the notation $A\times B$ means then one of the following is obvious: $W\subset  A\times B$, or $A\times B\subset W$. Whichever, is it a proper subset?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Can you please edit your post and add what your attempts at solving this problem? And, while you're at it, add an exclamation mark "!" before the link to the image and use [LaTeX / Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) in the equations.

Comment: Unless $W$ is related in some way to $A,B$, no direct comparison is possible.  You've relied on an image to frame the problem you want help with, but the lack of wording in your post may suggest to Readers that you have not digested the meaning of this problem.

Comment: @hardmath I am confused as to what the conclusion would be compared to the example I have given.

Comment: The example you were given does not match the problem you were given, but it is meant to be suggestive. If Tolkien, Austin, and Virgil were the only authors, and if LotR, PaP, and Iliad were the only books, then $\mathcal W$ would, indeed, be as given. What would $\mathcal A\times\mathcal B$ be under those circumstances?

Answer (score 3):

$A\times B=\{(r,k):\ r\in A,\ k\in B\}$, no additional restrictions.

$W=\{(r,k):\ r\in A,\ k\in B\text{ book }k\text{ written by author }r\}$, where you see that there is an extra restriction on the pairs.

Therefore $W\subset A\times B$, which tells you that $|W|\leq |A\times B|$.

Now, to determine if $|W|<|A\times B|$ there is extra information that would need to be used, is not explicitly given, and it is not clear if it can be assumed, but may be part of the intention.

Maybe $A$ and $B$ are finite. This seems reasonable in the real world. There are only finitely many books and authors.

Maybe one can assume that at least one book that was not written my some other author.

So, with these two assumptions, at least one pair in $A\times B$ is not in $W$. Since $|A\times B|$, and therefore $|W|$, is finite. It follows that $|W|<|A\times B|$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $a$ is an author, and $b$ is a book they've written, then $(a, b) \in W$ (by definition) and also $(a, b) \in A \times B$ (because that's how Cartesian products work). In fact, for any $(a, b) \in W$, $(a, b) \in A \times B$ is always true, so $W \subseteq A \times B$. This puts a boundary on one direction of their cardinalities.

The trickier question is whether $W  = A \times B$ or not, and that depends on how we're defining things. Essentially, is it possible to have $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ such that $(a, b) \notin W$? If so, then $W \subset A \times B$ ($W$ is a *proper* subset of the product set, since it's missing elements); but if all possible combinations of author and book title exist, then $W = A \times B$ and their cardinalities are equal.

There are two main possibilities of how you could have the sets equal:

1. $A = \{a\}$, i.e. we have listed only one author, and in $B$ we only have books that author has written; e.g. $A = \{\text{Tolkien}\}$ and $B = \{\text{Hobbit, LOTR}\}$.
2. We somehow find a set of authors such that for every book in $B$, all of those authors have written those books. For example, if $B = \{\text{My Story}\}$, and $A = \{\text{Julie Coillard, Kamala Das, Marilyn Monroe}\}$ (since, according to Wikipedia, all three of these people have written a book called "My Story".

That said, is is provably possible for $W = A \times B$, so $W$ is not *always* a proper subset of $A \times B$, and hence the cardinality can be less than or equal.